# Почему нельзя создать массив на миллион элементов на Си?

Tags: c, массивы

Почему нельзя создать массив на миллион элементов на Си? 
или
Почему этот код не работает?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int array[1000000] = {0};

    printf("successfully created\n");
}
```

Comment: Если я правильно помню C, в нём нельзя так инициализировать массив. Что за ошибку то показывает?

Comment: Как не работает? А что пишет?

Comment: Размер стека на 4 мегабайта не тянет... Скомпилируется оно нормально, а вот работать может и не захотеть.

Comment: Внутри функций значения переменные занимают место в стеке. Вашей переменной для `array` будет выделено четыре миллиона байт. Значит маленький размер стека.

Comment: А можно перейти на 64битную систему и скорее всего все отработает (стек обычно 8мб)

Comment: при таком количестве элементов тут уже нужно выделить память, например функцией malloc. А потом не забыть почистить.

Comment: зачем столько на стеке - не понятно...

Comment: `int *array = malloc(1000000);`

Comment: можно и не чистить - если выделение не в цикле ;)

Answer (score 1):

Напишите так:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int array[1000000] = {0};

int main(){

    printf("successfully created\n");

return 0;
}
```

Должно сработать. :-)

Comment: Должно сработать, но не работает! Можно создать массив на 1, 10, 100 ... 100000 элементов. Но на миллион уже нельзя. Если это важно, компилятор GCC

Comment: @jpedro, с чего вы взяли-то, что не работает?

Comment: Я компилировал этот код. exe'шник не выполняется. Работает для, например,                 
int array[100] = {0};

Comment: @jpedro Не знаю что там у Вас за чудесный GCC такой. Чтобы статически система не могла разместить какие-то жалкие 4 мегабайта, такого мы со времен MS DOS не слыхали. Например онлайн компилятор http://cpp.sh/ вполне работает с этим кодом. А там скорее всего тоже GCC стоит. И еще можно проверить другие онлайн компиляторы, в некоторых даже можно указать конкретную версию компилятора, в том числе GCC. Может у Вас в системе свопинг отключен? Или еще какие-то странные настройки имеются? Платформа-то какая? Часом не raspberry pi? ОЗУ в системе сколько? ОС какая?